# Infinite Grid in 2.80

Tags: versions

Hi I've just downloaded Blender 2.80
I was wandering if there is a way of making the floor grid in 2.80 a little bit more like it was in 2.79 when it actualy was 8x8 and not infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way of of limiting the grid to let's say 10 squares. You could however disable it under "Overlays", create a plane and subdivide it with a right click. Then under Object Panel > Viewport Display set "Display as" to Wire and check "All edges".

[image: Object Panel]