# Grid Floor Size changing Issue in fspy

Tags: fspy

I want to match the grid floor size to my image floor exact size. How can I do it? Please help.[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129259/how-do-i-change-the-grid-floor

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127914/infinite-grid-in-2-80